# Why was Yuki disappearing?

Tags: wixoss

In episode 11 of Selector Spread Wixoss, Yuki started to disappear because, according to Mayu, she broke the contract of being an eternal girl by not keeping her wish to make Iona "Not Iona anymore."  But she's not an eternal girl anymore, she's an LRIG, so she shouldn't be bound to keeping other people's wishes from when she was in different human bodies (different eternal girls) in the past.  So it makes no sense to me why she'd be disappearing.  An LRIG shouldn't have any obligation to fulfill any wishes to anyone; only eternal girls have that obligation.  Any ideas?